# How can I develop an ASP.NET web application using Hadoop as Database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, hadoop

I want to develop an ASP.NET web application that uses Hadoop DFS as database. I have already installed and configured the Hadoop on a Windows Server 2008 R2 in my intranet. Now, I want to use it as a database for developing my ASP.NET web application. Please suggest.

Comment: can we make dsn of this database? if we can make we can use.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all Hadoop is not a DB. It is a FS(HDFS)+a computation framework. If you are looking for a scalable DB kind of tool that runs on top of Hadoop, you might find [HBase](http://hbase.apache.org) a good fit. If you are aware, MS also has its own Hadoop offering, [HDInsights](https://www.hadooponazure.com/). Through HDInsights you could use HBase conveniently on your Windows machine. If you need some help on how to configure HDInsights, you could have a look at this [link](http://cloudfront.blogspot.in/2012/10/how-to-install-and-use-hdinsight-hadoop.html#.UcGZHUAW38s). You can find some examples as well on their website. They also provide Hadoop .NET sdk that that makes it easier to work with Hadoop from .NET. Have a look at [this](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/hdinsight/howto-net-libraries/).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I know Hadoop is not a DB, it is  a DFS. I mentioned it as Database because I want to use it instead of any conventional RDBMS like Sql Server. I have some confusion regarding HDInsights that it is only cloud based. Can I use it for Hadoop which is installed on a windows server on intranet? I have not tried HBase yet. As per your suggestion, I will try this.

Comment: You are welcome Atul. I don't think you can use HDFS as a RDBMS all by itself. But you could Hive to serve the purpose. And even if it was possible I would never suggest you to do that as hadoop is not meant for transactional and real time needs. And you can use HDInsight on premise as well. The link which I have shown above shows you how to run it on Windows 7 desktop.

Comment: Yes Tariq, I am not using Hadoop as RDBMS. As, my application has huge data requirements that is why I am going with Big Data Hadoop. Thanks for sharing that I can also use it on Windows 7 desktop. Now, I will follow the procedure mentioned in the links given by you. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome Atul. If you really need a DB for your BigData, I would strongly suggest you to have a look at HBase or something like that. The reason why i'm stressing on not to use HDFS is that being a FS it lacks random read/write capability, which is the first reason why we go for a DB.